# tcsh filename globbing broken?

Tags: command-line

'[3-4]' expands as if I had asked for '[0-4]'. This occurs with letters as well:

```
ls
file_0  file_1  file_2  file_3  file_a  file_b  file_c

ls file_[2-3]
file_0  file_1  file_2  file_3


ls file_[b-c]
file_0  file_1  file_2  file_3  file_a  file_b  file_c
```

Enumerations work as expected:

```
ls file_[2bc]
file_2 file_b   file_c
```

Is this a known bug or have I suddenly been teleported to an alternate universe?  Do you see this on your system (csh or tcsh)?  Is it fixed in tcsh 6.22 ?  Thanks!

```
tcsh --version
tcsh 6.21.00 (Astron) 2019-05-08 (x86_64-apple-darwin) options wide,nls,dl,bye,al,kan,sm,rh,color,filec

macOS 10.14.4
```

Comment: What happens if you start `tcsh` without reading `.tcshrc` and `.login` ?

Comment: @fd0 Most probably the same. I tried on Big Sur, same behvaviour. And I haven't used tcsh/csh on macOS at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same happens on Big Sur. But the standard `tcsh` in macOS hasn't changed for years, you can install `tcsh 6.22.03 (Astron) 2020-11-18` via Homebrew.

```
% ls
foo_1   foo_2   foo_3   x
% echo foo_[1-4]
foo_1 foo_2 foo_3
% echo foo_[2-4]
foo_2 foo_3
% tcsh --version
tcsh 6.22.03 (Astron) 2020-11-18 (unknown-apple-darwin) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,color,filec
```